# For every matrix $A$ mod $r$, is there a nonzero vector $\vec x$ so that $A \vec x$ has 0 mod $r$ nonzero entries?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, number-theory

#### Definitions:

Let $\lVert \vec x \rVert_0$ be equal to the number of nonzero entries in $\vec x$. I'll write $\mathbb{Z} / r\mathbb{Z}$, the ring of integers mod $r$, as $\mathbb{Z}_r$ for brevity.

#### What I'd like to prove:

For all $r \geq 2 \in \mathbb{N}$ (not necessarily prime), for all sufficiently large $n \in \mathbb{N}$, for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$, and for all $A \in \mathbb{Z}_r^{m \times n}$, there exists some nonzero $\vec x \in \mathbb{Z}_r^{n \times 1}$ such that $\lVert A \vec x  \rVert_0 \equiv 0 \mod r$, where both the matrix multiplication and the 0-"norm" are taken mod $r$.

#### Current progress:

Certainly when $m < n$, $A$ is singular, so the statement holds.

When $r$ is prime, the full statement holds: we can use Fermat's Little Theorem to rewrite $\lVert A \vec x \rVert_0 \mod r$ as a polynomial in the entries of $\vec x$. The degree of the polynomial (in terms of the components of $\vec x$) is $r-1$. But any polynomial that is nonzero exactly on nonzero inputs (that is, a polynomial representing $OR$ over $\mathbb{Z}_r$) has degree at least $n$: the unique polynomial that is 1 only on $\vec 0$ and 0 otherwise is $NOR(\vec x) = \prod_i (1-x_i^{r-1})$, which has degree $n(r-1)$. If we had a polynomial representing $OR$ of degree $< n$, we could write $NOR(\vec x) = 1 - OR(\vec x)^{r-1}$, which would have degree $< n(r-1)$, a contradiction. So, as soon as $n \geq r$ there must be a nonzero $\vec x$ that produces a 0-norm congruent to 0 mod $r$.

I'm pretty sure when $r$ is a prime power, similar polynomial tricks will also work.

But when $r$ is composite with distinct prime factors, I run out of tricks and get stuck.

Comment: If $m = n \ge r$, either $A$ is not invertible and there is $\vec x \ne 0$ such that $A\vec x = 0$, or $A$ *is* invertible and the non-zero vector $e_1 + \dots + e_r$ will have a (necessarily non-zero) preimage.

Comment: @JBL $\lVert \cdot \rVert_0$ counts the number of _nonzero_ entries, so if $A$ is the zero matrix you'd get $\lVert A \vec x \rVert_0 = 0$ regardless of $\vec x$.

Comment: Yes, apparently I can't read :-/.  Apologies.

Comment: what if A is the identity matrix?

Comment: @sb945 If $A$ is the identity matrix, then as soon as $n \geq r$ we can construct $\vec x$ as $r$ 1s and $n-r$ 0s, so that $\lVert A \vec x \rVert_0 = \lVert \vec x \rVert_0 = r = 0$ mod $r$.

Answer (score 0):

So with the author's comment in OP I get to understand that it intends to prove that for any given $A\in\mathbb Z_r^{m\times n}$ with $n\ge 2$, either there is some $y\in\mathbb Z_r^n$ so that Ay=0 or there is some $x\in\mathbb Z_r^n$ so that no entry in Ax is 0.

We shall first obtain such a rational vector, and then scale and modulo it to get a non-zero vector in $\mathbb Z_r^n$

There are two case:

Case 1:
There is at least one row in A that is identically 0, which indicates that $\ker(A)$ is non-empty and by density we can find some $x'\in\mathbb Q^n$ so that Ax'=0

Case 2:
No row in A is identically 0, then the set $\{x: \text{at least one entry in Ax is } 0\}$ is the union of finitely many hyperplanes, thus by density we can find $x'\in\mathbb Q^n$ so that no entry in Ax' is 0.

In either case, by the same reason as in case 2, $x'\in\mathbb Q^n$ can actually be chosen in such a way that lcm of the denominators of its entries is not in $r\mathbb Z$.

Therefore we can scale x' properly to get an $x\in Z^n$ with the same property, and mod entries of x by r to obtain a non-zero desired vector in $\mathbb Z_r^n$

Remark: I have seen essentially the same statement, which is used as an intermediate step in Proposition 3 of the paper:
B.Farkas, M.Matolcsi, P.Mora: On Fuglede's conjecture and the existence of universal spectra. Journal of Fourier Analysis and Applications, 12(5), 483-494. 2006.
The steps above are also taken and adapted from there.

Comment: I don't see how having an identically 0 _row_ in $A$ implies $A$ has a nontrivial kernel.

Comment: right, what I wrote works only when m=n and n is multiple of r.

Comment: I think it actually works when $m \geq n$, or at least I don't see the part that depends on $A$ being square. But it doesn't work when $n$ is a multiple of $r$; it works when the _number of nonzero rows_ in $A$ is a multiple of $r$. So unfortunately this doesn't necessarily produce $\vec x$ so that $\lVert A \vec x \rVert_0 \equiv 0 \mod r$.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain as i would do it:

- Case 1: m<n
  In this case, A is singular, so the statement holds trivially.
- Case 2: m=n
  In this case, ‖Ax⃗‖0≡‖x⃗‖0modr for all x⃗∈Zn×1r. Since n is sufficiently large, there exists some nonzero x⃗∈Zn×1r such that ‖x⃗‖0≡1modr. Therefore, ‖Ax⃗‖0≡0modr.
- Case 3: m>n
  We will prove by contradiction that there exists some nonzero x⃗∈Zn×1r such that ‖Ax⃗‖0≡0modr.

Suppose to the contrary that there exists no nonzero x⃗∈Zn×1r such that ‖Ax⃗‖0≡0modr. This means that for all nonzero x⃗∈Zn×1r, we have ‖Ax⃗‖0≠0modr.

We can write ‖Ax⃗‖0 as a polynomial in the entries of x⃗, which has degree n(r−1). Since r is not prime, there exist distinct primes p and q such that p∣r and q∣r. Therefore, we can write ‖Ax⃗‖0 as a product of two polynomials, one of which has degree n(p−1) and the other of which has degree n(q−1).

Let f(x⃗) be the polynomial that has degree n(p−1). We know that f(x⃗)≠0 for all nonzero x⃗. This means that there exists some nonzero x⃗ such that f(x⃗) is divisible by p.

Let y⃗=x⃗/p. Then y⃗∈Zn×1r and ‖Ay⃗‖0≡0modr. This contradicts our assumption that there exists no nonzero x⃗∈Zn×1r such that ‖Ax⃗‖0≡0modr.

Therefore, our original assumption must have been wrong, and there must exist some nonzero x⃗∈Zn×1r such that ‖Ax⃗‖0≡0modr.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: "We can write $\lVert A \vec x \rVert_0$ as a polynomial in the entries of $\vec x$..." I don't see how this is true for composite $r$ with at least two distinct prime factors.